# Reverse index keeping ordered values

Tags: python, list, reverse

I was trying to write a mod11 ( off-topic perhaps ) function and I came up with this:

```
print [(i,v) for i,v in reversed(list(enumerate('ABCDEFG'[::-1])))]

>>[(6, 'A'), (5, 'B'), (4, 'C'), (3, 'D'), (2, 'E'), (1, 'F'), (0, 'G')]
```

and if I change it up a little bit:

```
print [(i,v) for i,v in reversed(list(enumerate('ABCDEFG'))[::-1])]

>>[(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'D'), (4, 'E'), (5, 'F'), (6, 'G')]
```

Could someone help me understand what is going on regarding the `reversed()` and the `[::-1]`? Why is the index being reversed but the values not?

Comment: It may help to realize that `reversed(list(enumerate('ABCDEFG'))[::-1])` is the same as `list(enumerate('ABCDEFG'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `reversed` and `[::-1]` will reverse the list (or string) they are applied to.

- In the first case, you reverse the string, giving `"GFE..."`, enumerate the reversed string, giving `[(0, 'G'), (1, 'F'), ...]`, and then reverse the enumeration again, resulting in `[(6, 'A'), (5, 'B'), ...]`.

  ```
  [(i,v) for i,v in reversed(list(enumerate('ABCDEFG'[::-1])))]
  ```
- In the second case, you enumerate the string, giving `[(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), ...]`, and then reverse that enumeration with `[::-1]` and immediately reverse it again with `reverse`, resulting in `[(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), ...]`.

  ```
  [(i,v) for i,v in reversed(list(enumerate('ABCDEFG'))[::-1])]
  ```

Thus, in the first case, the string is reversed twice, and the indices just once, while in the second case both the letters in the string and the indices are reversed twice, resulting in their original order.

Comment: Thank you! It looks a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that indices here is something special. `enumerate` is just replacing element with tuple (index, element). After you do that, other functions operate on list of tuples and it doesn't matter what they contain. In other words, in first case with `[::-1]` you reverse letters, in second case with `[::-1]` you reverse tuples (index, letter).